# .map values by grouping by key

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

My data coming in looks like:

```
replaceName =
0: {Number: 1, newNumber:"1", name: "tom" }
1: {Number: 2, newNumber: "2", name: "john" }
2: {Number: 2, newNumber: "2", name: "Greg" }
3: {Number: 3, newNumber: "3", name: "Phil" }
4: {Number: 4, newNumber: "4", name: "tim" }
5: {Number: 4, newNumber: "4", name: "paul" }
```

I want to group the values that are the same for `newNumber`.

The output will be similar to this:

```
result = [
1: {Number: 1, newNumber:"1", name: "tom" }
2: [{Number: 2, newNumber: "2", name: "john" }, {Number: 2, newNumber: "2", name: "Greg" }]
3: {Number: 3, newNumber: "3", name: "Phil" }
4: [{Number: 4, newNumber: "4", name: "tim" }, {Number: 4, newNumber: "4", name: "paul" }]
```

I have tried a few ways, the closest I have come to is:

```
    const result = _.mapValues(replaceName, function(group, key) {
        return key === 'newNumber' ? _.groupBy(group, 'newNumber') : group;
  });
```

Which I know does not work in my scenario. The key of the new object also matches newNumber as in my expected result.

Any help here would be appreciated. Using lodash and react.

Comment: the output result is not valid in this form, did you mean to write 2: [...] (array of objects) instead?

Comment: Yes I will update

Comment: Is the receiving data a json arrray

Comment: Yes it is a json array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `groupBy` do. Using `groupBy` only is enough:

```js
const result = _.groupBy(replaceName, 'newNumber')
```